# Magento 2 RESTful API update category

Tags: magento2, category, api, rest-api

I am using Magento 2.0.11. I would like to use the RESTful API

```
(HTTP:// magento2URL/index.php/rest/V1/categories/(category ID))
```

to change the "Is Active" attribute of one category from True to False.

[image]

The JSON packet I am sending is as following:

```
{"category": {"id":399,"parentId": 2,"name": "PRIMADONA","isActive": false,"position": 0,"includeInMenu": false}
```

and I also tried:

```
{"category": {"id":399,"parentId": 2,"name": "PRIMADONA","is_active": false,"position": 0,"include_in_menu": false}
```

The magento backend responded http 200 OK but the is_active is not updated:

> < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < 
>   * Closing connection #0 {"id":399,"parent_id":2,"name":"PRIMADONA",**"is_active":true**,"position":0,"level":2,"children":"","updated_at":"2017-08-04
>   08:38:......................>

I also tried adding "all" into the RESTful URL:

```
(magento2URL/index.php/rest/all/V1/categories/<category ID>)
```

But none of the above methods are working for me.

Is there any workaround to update the "Is Active" attribute of one category?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so i figured it out.
**URL:**
`/rest/V1/categories/18217`
**payload:**
`{
  "category": {
    "is_active": false
  }
}`

Good Luck

Comment: This worked with 2.1.6